# Is there a way to print from a key in a value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

How can i print the value "that" in the dictionary below

```
x = { 'k1':['val1', 'val2', 'val3', {'we': ['need','to', 'go', {'deeper': [1,2,3, 'that'] } ] } ] }
```

i have tried all i know but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities.

One of them would be `print(x['k1'][-1]['we'][-1]['deeper'][-1])`.

Have a look at both `list` and `dictionary` indexing. There are always ways to go over keys, indices, values, etc. It depends on what you want to achieve and what data you expect to be there

Comment: Thank you, how about if we index from the left?

Comment: `print(x['k1'][3]['we'][3]['deeper'][3])` since we start counting the list-elements from 0